# Compare getdate() with two different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables:

```
T1                        T2
id   Effdate              E_id   DOB
--------------           ------------
1    20161212              2     1950-02-16 00:12:24
2    20130124              5     1978-01-16 10:14:30
```

I want to compare `getdate() < Maxdate(effdate, DOB)`?

I am getting datetime conversion error.

for example : `getdate() < MAXDATE( 20161212 , 1950-02-16 00:12:24)`

expected result should be from table `T1`:

```
id  Effdate
--------------
1   20161212
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (`getdate()` is a product specific function.)

Comment: Add the expected result. Effdate and DOB column data types?

Comment: Data types for Effdate(varchar) and DOB(datetime)

Comment: You probably have a type mismatch.  What is your `MAXDATE` function expecting?

Comment: MAXDATE is for getting the max date between two dates i.e. effdate and DOB. I want to then compare the result with cuurentdate. So if currentdate is less than the maxdate(result), i want to pick that record form the table

Comment: maxdate() might be returning null or something that is not a date.  please post the code for the function.   
Since Effdate is varchar it is likely that it has bad dates in it.   Try select * from T1 where isdate( Effdate ) != 1;

Comment: @user3183055 have you tried the solution below?

Answer (score 0):

If id in both tables are correspondent on `id = E_id` you can UNION them and GROUP BY `id`:

```
;WITH T1 AS (
SELECT  1 id,
        CAST('20161212' as varchar(10)) Effdate
UNION ALL
SELECT  2,
        '20130124'
), T2 AS (
SELECT  1 E_id,
        CAST('1950-02-16 00:12:24' as datetime) DOB
UNION ALL
SELECT  2,
        '1978-01-16 10:14:30'
)

SELECT  id,
        MAX(CAST(Effdate as datetime)) as MD
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM T1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM T2
    ) t
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(CAST(Effdate as datetime)) >= GETDATE()
```

Will bring you expected result